# an issue with copy in EditText (android)

Tags: java, android, android-edittext

I'm getting this error  when trying to copy text in editText :

```
    Exception java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: "res/drawable/edit_text_material.xml"
java.lang.Integer.invalidInt (Integer.java:138)
java.lang.Integer.parse (Integer.java:410)
java.lang.Integer.parseInt (Integer.java:367)
com.android.internal.util.XmlUtils.convertValueToInt (XmlUtils.java:133)
android.content.res.TypedArray.getInt (TypedArray.java:357)
android.view.animation.Animation.<init> (Animation.java:248)
android.view.animation.AnimationSet.<init> (AnimationSet.java:81)
android.view.animation.AnimationUtils.createAnimationFromXml (AnimationUtils.java:117)
android.view.animation.AnimationUtils.createAnimationFromXml (AnimationUtils.java:95)
android.view.animation.AnimationUtils.loadAnimation (AnimationUtils.java:76)
android.widget.Editor$SelectionPopupWindow.createAnimations (Editor.java:4086)
android.widget.Editor$ActionPinnedPopupWindow.<init> (Editor.java:2543)
android.widget.Editor$ActionPopupWindow.<init> (Editor.java:3577)
android.widget.Editor$SelectionPopupWindow.<init> (Editor.java:4074)
android.widget.Editor$SelectionHandleView.getActionPopupWindow (Editor.java:5337)
android.widget.Editor$SelectionModifierCursorController.show (Editor.java:5305)
android.widget.Editor.startSelectionActionMode (Editor.java:1715)
android.widget.Editor.performLongClick (Editor.java:1020)

android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:5438)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (ZygoteInit.java:738)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:628)
```

This is my layout:

```
       <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:textColorHint="#565d66">

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/userEditText"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:hint="@string/registration.hint.user"
                    android:textColor="#565d66"
                    android:theme="@style/Custom.EditText" />

            </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>



// this is the theme i'm using in editText:

      <style name="Custom.EditText" parent="Base.Widget.AppCompat.EditText">
        <item name="colorControlNormal">#565d66</item>
        <item name="colorControlHighlight">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    </style>
```

android version : 6.0.1 , device : redmi note 4

Comment: can you please share your java code.

Comment: where are you using `edit_text_material` theme ??

Comment: exception is clear: try to parse path as number

Comment: i don't have any additional code , just inflating EditText and using getText().toString() method

Comment: i'm note using "edit_text_material " theme , i'm just using the theme i mentioned above

Comment: note : this error is not occurring in other phones

Comment: Occurred on a Xiaomi device?

Comment: Happens to me on an Xiaomi device too.

Comment: I'm having that problem on a Xiaomi device too, weird, it must be some particular SO implementation leading to that

Answer (score 2):

Well, I also encounter this problem and I solve it by removing the style parent.

```
<style name="Custom.EditText">
    <item name="colorControlNormal">#565d66</item>
    <item name="colorControlHighlight">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/colorPrimary</item>
</style>
```

I think the cause of the error is each smartphone vendor make custom UI and we need to use their default style for edittext.

Just try to make additional edittext without style and try to copy the text. Compare it with the one that have custom style, the context menu will be weird.

PS: Sorry for my bad english

Answer (score 1):

You add color resource.

```
<color name="customEditText">#565d66</color>
```

and modify your style code.

```
<style name="Custom.EditText" parent="Base.Widget.AppCompat.EditText">
    <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/customEditText</item>
    <item name="colorControlHighlight">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/colorPrimary</item>
</style>
```

You try this